# How do I intersect two data.frames in R?

Tags: r, google-genomics

I have two tables that are in the data.frame structure. Table 1 contains a column of 200 gene IDs (letters and numbers) and Table 2 contains a list of 4,000 gene IDs (in rows) as well as 20 additional columns. I want to intersect these two tables and generate a new Table 3 that contains the 200 gene IDs as well as the associated information in the 20 columns.

table3 <- table1%n%table2

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [ask] and [mcve] ... then **edit your question!**

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question is really about a well-documented task. You can have a look to `left_join` and `right_join` from the package `dplyr`

Answer (score 2):

You want something like

```
table3 <- merge(table1, table2, by.x="id", by.y="id", all.x=T, all.y=F)
```

You might also be able to do subsetting with something like this:

```
table3 <- table2[table2$id %in% table1$id,]
```

A reprex would have made this post more likely to get a good response, but you should have been able to find something to help you with a little searching. If these don't work because you have a unique problem no one has asked before, give is a reprex and we can try to give you alternative solutions.

edit: for a little more context, [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47540159/how-to-merge-two-separate-data-sets-with-common-values-in-a-column/47540226) a similar question I replied to last week and [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right) a great post on understanding merges.

Comment: Thanks so much. I cannot tell you how much I was searching before your post to this. Definitely learning how to search this awesome resource better. Thanks again.

Comment: I've learned that one of my most valuable skills is not being able to solve problems but knowing the keywords to search for to find others' solutions to my problems.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the `dplyr` package. It works more intuitively than `merge` in my opinion.

you can just type:

```
table3 <- left_join(table1, table2, by = "unique_id")
```

Comment: OuterJ <- merge(x = Oct, y = Sept, by = "CONTACT_ID", all = TRUE)

LeftJ <- merge(x = Oct, y = Sept, by = "CONTACT_ID", all.x = TRUE)

RightJ <- merge(x = Oct, y = Sept, by = "CONTACT_ID", all.y = TRUE)

CrossJ <- merge(x = Oct, y = Sept, by = NULL)